# how to use await/async in for loop

Tags: node.js, for-loop, asynchronous, async-await

Why the code print this way ??

await can not be used under loop?

```
>>>>> START
1
```

The expect result is '>>>>> START 1 2 3 >>>>> END'

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3]
async function print() {
  for (let n of arr) {
    await new Promise(
      resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log(n);
          resolve;
        }, 1000)
      }
    );
  }
}

async function main() {
  console.log(">>>>> START");
  await print();
  console.log(">>>>> END");
}

main()
```

Comment: Try this ```setTimeout(() => {
          console.log(n);
          resolve();
        }, 1000)```

Comment: Because of first promise doesn't resolve so your code wait until the first promise get resolve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple typo, you are not calling the `resolve` function. You need to actually invoke it, otherwise your promise will never resolve and your code will never continue (note the addition of parentheses after `resolve` in your `print` function):

```
async function print() {
  for (let n of arr) {
    await new Promise(
      resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log(n);
          resolve(); // invoke the function
        }, 1000)
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Also, each `console.log` call prints on a new line so the output won't be exactly what you expect, instead it'll be more like:

```
>>>>> START
1
2
3
>>>>> END
```